# Node module express redirect throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just need to redirect from /chat to /chat/auth . I'm using express and mysql. I tried `res.redirect('/auth')` . Using it gave the following error:

```
D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
  ^

at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:570:31)
at ServerResponse.header (D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
at ServerResponse.redirect (D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:953:18)
at Query.<anonymous> (D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\server.js:47:28)
at Query.<anonymous> (D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Query._callback (D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
at Query.Sequence.end (D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
at Query.EofPacket (D:\anshu\js3\socketChat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8)
```

The error does not appear when not using `res.redirect` , leading it to unquestionable assumption that the redirect is behind the error. Also, the error points to the line. I have spent many hours scouring the internet for any possible solution to this error, but have found none that provide any help or even insight for this error. No one else seems to have had this exact same error. Any help will be greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
res.redirect("/chat/auth")
```

that should do the job

Comment: res.redirect gives the error above.

Comment: i don't think its a redirection error then you must debug for the error it must be coming from inside of the handler.

Comment: it clearly points to the line. Besides, It only occurs when the line is included..

Comment: information provided is incomplete, Provide more information on that

Comment: I included all the info. The error message is complete....